# How to change date format for ajax columns data?

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is the code and I cannot find anything that works for this

```
$(function () {
    var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ url('activity-lists') }}",
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'data', name: 'data' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
        ],
    });
});
```

This is the result `2023-04-18T06:42:22.000000Z` and I wanted it to be `04/18/2023 06:42:22`.

Comment: "_cannot find anything that works_" - There are [DataTables date formatting questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+date+format+site%253Astackoverflow.com) on Stack Overflow. Did none of those help you?

Comment: Also take a look at the [date and time examples](https://datatables.net/examples/datetime/index.html) on the official DataTables web site. These include datetime formatting examples, using Luxon and Moment.

Comment: Side note: Just a warning - you are transforming a datetime string with an implied timezone (`Z` for UTC) to a string with no timezone - but with the same time. Depending on where in the world your users are (and whether they are in a daylight saving time zone), this may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
  $(function () {
  var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{{ url('activity-lists') }}",
    columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
        { data: 'data', name: 'data' },
        {
           data: 'created_at', 
           name: 'created_at',
           def: function () { return new Date(); },
           displayFormat: 'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
        },
    ],
  });
});
```

Here is some exemples :

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/dates/formatting-client.html

Comment: I get `datetime.js:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')` error

Comment: Did you follow the link that I posted ? There are some jquery libraries to add to your page. At the end of the example frame you can see them.